# Adding more than one MessageListener using Smack API

Tags: java, android, smack

I have two different types of messages and I am handling these message by two different listener.

I am adding listener in one class

```
 public DrawingXmppServices(SurfaceViewCanvas surfaceView) {
            chat = chatManager.createChat(BUDDY, new MyChatListener());
            chat.addMessageListener(new MyChatListener());
            receiver = surfaceView;
        }
public void sendDrawingData(String drawingData, String buddyId) {
        try {
            chat.sendMessage(drawingData);
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And On other class

```
public InstantMessageXmpp(CanvasActivity canvasActivity) {
        receiver = (MessageReceiver) canvasActivity;
        chat = chatManager.createChat(BUDDY, this);
        chat.addMessageListener(this);
    }
public void sendIM(String message, String buddyID) {
        try {
            chat.sendMessage(message);
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I call `InstantMessageXmpp` to send its packet but the listener of `DrawingXmppServices` is called. What mistake is I am doing?
Please guide me. Any suggestion can help me. Thank you

Comment: I don't know the Smack API but the second listener is referred to as 'this' and I don't see which class you are in. It also seems like you set the listener twice. Once via the createChat method and once via the addMessageListener

Comment: Not worked. The listener that is added first is the one that is called :(